# How to embed binary data in XML using XML Builder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I am using the [XML `Builder` gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/builder) to deliver XML data from one app to another app. Now we'd like to using the same channel to send binary data (PDF documents stored in database). The controller is something like:

```
@invoice = Invoice.first(:conditions => ['has_scanned = ?', 'Y'])
```

and the view `invoice.xml.builder`:

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version=>"1.0", :encoding=>"UTF-8"
xml.invoice(:invoice_no => @invoice.number, :pdf => @invoice.attachment)
```

Do I need to encode the `:pdf` data or `Builder` handles it good enough by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do something with the binary stream, because it has some invalid characters for XML.

Here is a document about [handle binary data in xml](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/98/07/binary/binary.html), it's language independent, just xml.

In this case, I think the easiest way to handle your attachment is using base64.
If `@invoice.attachment` is the binary string, use the code below, if not, get it:

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version=>"1.0", :encoding=>"UTF-8"
xml.invoice(:invoice_no => @invoice.number) do
  xml.pdf Base64.encode64(@invoice.attachment)
end
```

When you read the xml, decode the string with base64 format and get the binary string.

Wish it helps.